# Possible to change cell style when row is clicked WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, wpf-style

I want to add an arrow indicator to whatever row is currently selected in a WPF `DataGrid`. I am willing to change if someone has a better approach, but what I was going to do what use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and use two different styles for the cell and the row.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" Width="50" CanUserSort="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Name="txtID" Text="{Binding ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxLength="20" />
                <TextBox Name="txtArrow" Text="&#x21E8;" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding IsRowSelected, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Basically, I want the `txtArrow` textbox to show for only the selected row in the data grid. I am wondering if this can be achieved via pure XAML and styles.  I know WPF has a row indicator out of the box at the left most column, but unfortunately I need to make the indicator on the right side of the first column `txtID`.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the style, I used a `MultiDataTrigger` to show the arrow indicator I want based on what row is selected in the data grid.  Whether this is the best solution or not is up for debate, but the row indicator is merely an arrow text character within a grid (rather than a stackpanel) in my cell that shares space with another textbox.  Code shown below:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" Width="50" CanUserSort="False">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <Grid.ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <TextBox Name="txtID" Text="{Binding ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="20" />
            <TextBox Name="txtArrow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BaseOn="{StaticResource MyTextBoxStyle}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True" /> 
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="--&gt;" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" Width="50" CanUserSort="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Name="txtID" Text="{Binding ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MaxLength="20" />
                        <TextBox Name="txtArrow" Text="&#x21E8;" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBox.Visibility>
                                <Binding Path="IsSelected" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}">
                                    <Binding.Converter>
                                        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter/>
                                    </Binding.Converter>
                                </Binding>
                            </TextBox.Visibility>
                        </TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```